# Unable to set the Animated splash screen using Ionic 4+

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

**What i need** : Animated splash screen to be displayed when app is opening.

**What i did** :  i took the below video as ref https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-c0htV-kfm8 and added in below code  and instead of animated splash screen i am getting normal default splash screen only .

**cod**e:

```
   <ion-app>
  <div #customOverlay><img src="http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dancing-banana.gif" [hidden]="!splash">
  </div> 
  <ion-router-outlet [hidden]="splash"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

**.ts code**

```
          splash = true;
  @ViewChild('customOverlay',{static:false})customOverlay:ElementRef;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();

      setTimeout(function(){
       this.splash = false;
       this.customOverlay.nativeElement.style.display = 'none';     
      }, 3000);

    });
  }

**Config.xml**



   <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0" />
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: Is it os specific or it's not wokring at all ?

Comment: @TaylorRahul Not working at all for me i am testing it on android

Comment: Hello @dexter please give it a try ...... https://i.diawi.com/874xgH

Comment: I try to follow the video .. and its working for me ... if you think this is working .we will fix it up

Comment: Did you get a chance to install the demo app i have shared link with you

Comment: @TaylorRahul apk unavailable can u reupload again ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the packages

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-lottie-splashscreen
npm install @ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen --save
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Now add to /src/app/app.module.ts

```
import { LottieSplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/lottie-splash-screen/ngx';
```

and providers too.

[image: providers]

Now you need to download a json from lottiefiles.com, inside your src/assets folder.

[image: loading.json]

Ex: https://lottiefiles.com/43846-butterfly-loader

Add in config.xml:

```
<preference name="LottieAnimationLocation" value="www/assets/loading.json" />
<preference name="LottieFullScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="LottieLoopAnimation" value="true" />
```

[image]

Now you need to hide the splash screen. Add this.lottieSplashScreen.hide() to app.component.ts

[image: app.component.ts]

Run the app on your device

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

`ionic serve` does not work for this case

Answer (score -1):

Check Josh Morony tutorial about this. I used it in the past and it worked.

Here is the link for reference: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/

Comment: I followed his lecture only and using ionic router it is not working. and the i tried the same and posted it .

Comment: @Dexter I'm not sure i quite understand your comment. But, here are a couple of questions: Are you starting a fresh project with the latest version of ionic? Using capacitor or cordova?

Comment: Im usin ionic 5+ version and using cordova and if we use the gif splash screen using with out ion-router it is working and if we use with ion-router it is not working . And and im using in existing ionic project which is version 5

Comment: Use it in a modal that shows on top of your home page, then when the time is finished, hide the modal... 

Why do you want to put it on the main component? You shouldn't really modify that page. Also make sure you set this preferences on the config.xml

<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>